# Facebook authentication access token in graph api call in json

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to login with Facebook. I am following the below step.

1. I get the authorize code to hit https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth? where i am getting the code. Now i am trying to get the access_token from 
   the https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token? passing the requirement argument. I want to access token in json format. I am sending a get request on this url. I am getting error. If i directly open that url in browser , then it returns the access_token in html format. Please help me to how to get this token in json form using api Call.

Comment: Using javascript ? You are getting the value "access token" you need, why not just create your own JSON object and pass that value in ?

Comment: How to get the access token value using javascript can u help?? When i am sending the get request It fails.

Comment: why not just use the javascript sdk? > http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/